# using smach with actionlib

Tags: ros, executive-smach, actionlib, smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When using smach with actionlib actions, am I correct in saying that smach acts as the action client for the action server? So I don't need a separate action client anymore?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9228/using-smach-with-actionlib/) by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 475 on 2011-02-27

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is correct, if you use a [simple action state](http://www.ros.org/wiki/smach/Tutorials/SimpleActionState) Smach will construct the action client for you.

Similarly, when you create a [action server wrapper](http://www.ros.org/wiki/smach/Tutorials/Wrapping%20a%20SMACH%20Container%20With%20actionlib) for a Smach container, Smach will construct the action server for you.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5